# Remove item from ListView builder from a child widget

Tags: flutter

I need to be able to remove a specific item in a listview from a child widget. However, what is making this difficult is the fact that the ontap() delete funcitonality is defined in the child widget.

How can I change the state of the parent widget form the child?

Parent ListView Builder

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics:
      BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: snapshot
      .data.datas.length,
  itemBuilder:
      (context, index) {
    if (snapshot
            .data
            .datas[index]
            .daysToOccurrence >=
        0) {
      if (_isSearching ==
          false) {
        return OrganizationList(
           
            id: snapshot
                .data
                .datas[index]
                .id);
      } else {
        return snapshot
                .data
                .datas[index]
                .id
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(
                    _searchText
                        .toLowerCase())
            ? OrganizationList(
                
                id: snapshot
                    .data
                    .datas[
                        index]
                    .id,
              )
            : Container();
      }
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }),
```

OrganizationList Widget (Defined in the child widget)

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        await _organizationBloc
            .delete(widget.id);

        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      },
      child: Text(
        "Delete",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
      ),
    ))
```

Comment: Try voidCallback as parameter in child widget

Comment: Ok giving it a try. But how does that work with streams? Specifically, the snapshot is not a global list

Comment: I should clarify this ListView.Builder gets its data from a StreamBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The trick was to define a delete method in the parent widget, pass an ObjectKey() to the child widget, and a pass voidCallback parameter to the child widget.

The voidCallback will map to the delete method in the parent widget and you can call that function from the child widget.

Parent Widget

```
  void _deleteItem(Organization item, List<Organization> organizationList) {
    organizationList.remove(item);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Updated ListViewBuilder

```
ListView.builder(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics:
      BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: snapshot
      .data.datas.length,
  itemBuilder:
      (context, index) {
    if (snapshot
            .data
            .datas[index]
            .daysToOccurrence >=
        0) {
      if (_isSearching ==
          false) {
        return OrganizationList(
           key: ObjectKey(
            snapshot.data
                    .datas[
                index]),
                onDeleteClicked: () =>
              _deleteItem(
                  snapshot.data.datas[
              index], snapshot.data.datas),
            id: snapshot
                .data
                .datas[index]
                .id);
      } else {
        return snapshot
                .data
                .datas[index]
                .id
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(
                    _searchText
                        .toLowerCase())
            ? OrganizationList(
                
                id: snapshot
                    .data
                    .datas[
                        index]
                    .id,
              )
            : Container();
      }
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }),
```

Then in the child widget where I have the delete functionality I can call this:

```
widget.onDeleteClicked();
```